# Django-links to another view

Tags: python, django, url, view

Iv just started learning Django-I have a basic doubt:

**my views.py in an app named 'rango':**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def viewone(request):
 html="Welcome page" <a href="/rango/about/">About</a>
 return HttpResponse(html)


def about(request):
 return HttpResponse("This is the about page-documented!!")
```

**my urls.py in the project named "mysite":**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',

  url(r'^rango/',include('rango.urls')),
)
```

**urls.py in the rango folder**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^welcome/$', views.viewone, name='index'),
url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about_page')
```

So basically my welcome page needs to have a link to point to the about page-but an error is thrown and Im not able to configure the pointing link.Can someone help me..Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code  ...

You can go to the welcome page by accessing

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/welcome/
```

And little changes in view,.. should be like

```
html= "Welcome page" + '<a href="/rango/about/">About</a>'
```

Comment: Thanks-that solved it!It was just a pair of quotation marks missing-I feel rather silly.

Comment: @ashwinshanker happy you solved by fully understand your code,.